# Http client program error

Tags: java, apache, netbeans

I am using netbeans 7.4 on MAC. when compiling the following program I am getting some exception.

**My code :**

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.*;


import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.*;

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpMethodParams;


public class HttpClientSample 
{

      private static String url = "http://www.apache.org/"; 
      public static void main(String[] args) 
      {
       // Constructor for HttpClient  
          HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

       //Creeating a method

         GetMethod method = new GetMethod(url);

      method.getParams().setParameter(HttpMethodParams.RETRY_HANDLER, new DefaultHttpMethodRetryHandler(3,false));

      try
      {
          //Execute the method 
          int statusCode = client.executeMethod(method);
        //  System.out.println("vikas is my name ");

          if(statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK)
          {
              System.err.println("Method failes : " + method.getStatusLine());

          }

         //Read the response body
          byte[] responsebody = method.getResponseBody();

          //Print the response

          System.out.println(new String(responsebody));

      } 
      catch (HttpException e) 
      {
            System.out.println("fatal protocol violation: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
      }
      catch (IOException e )
      {
            System.out.println("fatal transport error : " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
      }
      finally 
      {
            // release the connection

          method.releaseConnection();
      }
    }
}
```

**After running the program i am getting the following exception :**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.<clinit>(HttpClient.java:66)
    at JavaApplication1.main(JavaApplication1.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
```

Can anyone help what is the problem in my code..
Thanks is advance..

Comment: There's no problem in the code. You're missing commons-logging library at a runtime. It may not be apparent from the code, but it's probably a runtime dependency of httpclient library.
I'm not sure how you run the application, but you need to add it to the classpath(in tomcat you just need to put it to the /lib directory) http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/download_logging.cgi

Comment: I am using netbeans.. and i have already include it in the netbeans library still i am getting exception..

Comment: I'm not familiar with netbeans, but assuming you're relying on the default project structure, you should add the run-time library via gui. Check File >> Project Properties >> Libraries >> Run-Time Libraries

Comment: Thanks NeplatnyUdaj, its working now...